# Available options for a source/destination format of Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

When we use `DataStreamReader API` for a format in Spark, we specify options for the format used using `option/options` method. For example, In the below code, I'm using `Kafka` as the source and passing the configuration required for the source through `option` method. Here I used only two options - `server details and topic configuration`. what I'm trying to find out is, what are all other options available for a data source or sink for a particular format, In this case, Kafka.  In the case of Kafka format, I could able find a few options which are stated in Kafka guide in Spark documentation, but where can I find other options available for Kafka format. I searched all the Spark documentation for this information but had no luck.

Is there any reference for options available for a data source/sink format in Spark(especially for structured streaming)?

```py
spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check Apache Spark official documentation for [Input sources](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources) and [Output Sinks](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks)

For Kafka configurations, you can use all Apache Kafka Consumer configurations as the [Structured Streaming Kafka Integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations) explains